# How do you rewrite this Scala class with variable fields in a more functional style?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

```
class MyClass {

  var myField = List.empty[Double]
  var mySecondField = List.empty[Double]

  def myMethod = {
     // code does some heavy computation
     myField = myComputationOutput
     mySecondField = mySecondComputationOutput
  }
}
```

I would like to avoid saving state in MyClass, but it seems convenient to store computed values during the myMethod call.

What are some design alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

If you are caching the results of those heavy computations, then you use a [memoize pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). You compute the result the first time and return it if the parameters are the same:

```
class MyClass {
  var myField = Option[List[Double]] = None
  var mySecondField = Option[List[Double]] = None

  def myMethod = {
    if ( ! myField.isDefined ) {
      myField = Some(myComputationOutput)
    }
    if ( ! mySecondField.isDefined ) {
      mySecondField = Some(mySecondComputationOutput)
    }
  }
}
```

If the values never change, you could consider computing them only the first time they are referenced, using lazy evaluation:

```
class MyClass {
  lazy val myField = myComputationOutput
  lazy val mySecondField = mySecondComputationOutput
}
```

Another approach is to consider that `MyClass` is really two classes, corresponding to the two phases, i.e., before and after the computation is done. Then, the mutability is a global state, rather than an amalgam of the states of two variables.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning `Unit` in myMethod you can return a new instance of MyClass.

Code using case class:

```
case class MyClass(myField: List[Double] = List.empty) {
   def myMethod = copy(myField = myComputationOutput)
}
```

or even better:

```
val myClass = MyClass(fields)
myClass.copy(myField = myComputationOutput)
```

This way you wont need `myMethod`.